# Convergence of $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 - 6x_n + 10$

Tags: limits, recursion

Let $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 - 6x_n + 10$. For what values of $x_0$ is $\{x_n\}$ convergent, and how does the value of the limit depend on $x_0$?

I know that if this recursion does converge, then it must converge to $2$ or $5$. I'm also pretty confident that $x_0 < 0$ and $x_0 > 5$ doesn't converge to these values. However, I'm having trouble making much progress past that. Some hints would be greatly apprecated!

Comment: [Duplicate](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1440505p8191380) in AOPS

Comment: Thanks for the reference, the solution given on this site is not complete.

Comment: Typically it's sensible to complete the square on such recursions, i.e., $x_{n+1}=(x_n-3)^2+1$. This gets even simpler if we let $y_k:=x_k-3$, making the recursion $y_{n+1}= y_n^2-2$ with fixed points at $y=-1,2$.

Comment: Hint: let $f(x) = x^2-6x+10$. $f(3 + z + z^{-1}) = 3 + z^2 + z^{-2}$.